# Как использовать main() вместо WinMain?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Я хочу написать GUI приложение для Windows, но мне не нравится что MS Visual Studio для этого надо писать `WinMain`. Хочу писать привычную `main()` или `main(argc, argv)` - как это сделать?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Прежде всего надо понимать, что ни `main()`, ни `WinMain()` - не являются "точками входа" .exe файла. Точкой входа (entry point) является некоторая функция, которая будет вызвана операционной системой при старте приложения. В С++ это функция рантайма (CRT), которая проводит инициализацию CRT, вызывает конструкторы глобальных объектов, и затем уже вызывает `main` или `WinMain`.

Линкеру передается параметр [`/subsystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx), который задает тип приложения, например `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` для GUI приложений, или `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` для консольных приложений. В первую очередь это нужно операционной системе - тип приложения прописывается в заголовке .exe файла, и по нему ОС понимает надо ли создавать окно консоли, или нет. Также, при помощи этого параметра линкер выбирает точку входа, которая будет использована *по-умолчанию*:

- `mainCRTStartup` (или`wmainCRTStartup`) - при использовании `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`. Вызывает `main` (или `wmain`)
- `WinMainCRTStartup` (или `wWinMainCRTStartup`) - при использовании `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`. Вызывает `WinMain` (или `wWinMain`).

Точку входа можно переопределить, передав линкеру параметр [`/entry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx). Для того чтобы использовать `main` в GUI приложении, мы должны вызвать линкер с параметрами `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` и `/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup`. Тогда ОС не будет создавать окно консоли, а CRT будет вызывать функцию `main`.

Значение параметра `/entry` можно переопределить в опциях проекта MSVS (linker > advanced > entry point). Либо его можно написать прямо в коде программы, с помощью `pragma comment`:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(linker, "/entry:mainCRTStartup")
int main() {
    ::MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"(^._.^)", L"Important message", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: Внеклассное чтение по данному вопросу: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/03/6644060.aspx