# Что означает @ после имени функции в C++?

Tags: c++, windows

Например, функция `WinMain@16`. Что означает "собака" и число после нее? У меня есть идея, что это общий размер параметров в байтах, но я не уверен в этом.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В си перегружать функции нельзя, поэтому, когда код компилируется, компилятор может использовать имена функций по назначению. В с++ можно перегружать функции, а в скомпилированном коде уже нет данных о аргументах. Поэтому, компилятор делает "манглирование". В данном случае просто кодирует размер аргументов и добавляет их таким образом. Это позволяет потом линковщику все собрать правильно в исполнимый файл.

Чуточку [больше](http://www.heaventools.ru/pe-explorer-unmangle.htm).

Answer (score 11):

Это вовсе не имя функции. Это компиляторозависимый name mangling — имя дополняется другой информацией для внутренних целей. Смысла вне конкретного компилятора и его конкретной версии не имеет.

Реальное имя функции — `WinMain`.

Если вы пытаетесь скомпилировать под Windows что-нибудь нестандартным компилятором, возможно, вам нужно почитать [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419427/10105).

Поскольку известно, что `WinMain` использует конвенцию вызова `__stdcall`, то согласно [официальной документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx) правильное имя должно быть `_WinMain@16` (спасибо @Abyx за уточнение).

Comment: @Abyx: Хм, странно. `__stdcall` было бы `_WinMain@16`, с подчёркиванием. А `__fastcall` было бы `@WinMain@16`, с `@`.

Comment: @Abyx: Ваша правда. Исправил ответ.